# Check for DNS records pointing to an IP

Tags: domain-name-system

I have noticed the past few weeks that I am receiving a lot more 404s than usual in my log.

When I looked at the errors I noticed that it's several different IP addresses looking for the same files which leads me to suspect that there might be DNS record(s) out there that could be pointing to my site.

Although this might be unlikely, I did come across difficulty trying to find all records pointing to the server's IP address as a reverse lookup does not meet this requirement.

How can one find all DNS records that point to a particular IP address or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance,

NOTE: Before anyone questions whether or not it is a link in my webapps pointing to it, it's not. For instance, there are queries looking for WordPress files and none of the apps on the server use WordPress.

Comment: It's impossible. Doesn't the logfiles contain the `Host:` headers in http requests?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have the client IP and the path they tried to access. I see some of the entries have a refer which is [Not my IP]/[path]. I will follow this up as I have the IP of the server referring to me for these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very uncommon to expect those malicious wordpress calls. The bots usually go over a for-loop of public IP addresses and once they find a live host they start the second step i.e. try logging in with a dictionary of username/passwords. You need not worry about them, simply block them or add a basic auth to your web app.